# Functions dplyr with rlang::last_error() in purrr::map loop in r

Tags: list, dplyr, data-manipulation, r-sf, rlang

I'm using a function to calculate the length of linestring per cell by ID and store in a list, convert each element of the list into a RasterLayer and turn that list into a RasterStack, average all layers and get a single raster.

```
#function

#  build_length_raster <- function(one_df) {

  intersect_list <- by(
    one_df , 
    one_df$sub_id,
    function(subid_df) sf::st_intersection(grid2, subid_df) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(length = as.numeric(sf::st_length(.))) %>%
      sf::st_drop_geometry()
  ) 
  
  list_length_grid <- purrr::map(intersect_list, function(x) 
    x %>% dplyr::left_join(x=grid2, by="cell", copy=T) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(length=length) %>%
      dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric,coalesce,0)
  )
   list_length_raster <- purrr::map(list_length_grid, function(x) 
    raster::rasterize(x, r, field="length", na.rm=F, background=0)
  )

  list_length_raster2 <- unlist(list_length_raster, recursive=F)
  
  raster_stack <- raster::stack(list_length_raster2)
  
  raster_mean <- raster::stackApply(
    raster_stack, 
    indices = rep(1,nlayers(raster_stack)), 
    fun = "mean", na.rm = TRUE)
#}
```

The function presents a step where, in order for the resulting grid of st_intersection() to have the same number of cells as it had initially, I use left_join(by="cell" column).Then I use mutate() to replace the NA's with 0. When I run the function steps for one dataframe from the list, it works perfectly, but when I put it inside map() to do this in a list, I get this error, which seems to refer to the dplyr functions:

```
final_list <- purrr::map(mylist, build_length_raster)

> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `cell`.
Backtrace:
  1. purrr::map(mylist, build_length_raster)
 15. dplyr:::left_join.data.frame(., x = grid, by = "cell", copy = T)
 16. dplyr:::join_mutate(...)
 17. dplyr:::join_cols(...)
 18. dplyr:::standardise_join_by(by, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names)
 19. dplyr:::check_join_vars(by$y, y_names)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Is there a way to solved this problem?

**MYDATA example**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(purrr)
library(raster)

#data example
id <- c("844", "844", "844", "844", "844","844", "844", "844", "844", "844",
        "844", "844", "845", "845", "845", "845", "845","845", "845", "845", 
        "845","845", "845", "845")
sub_id <- c("2017_844_1", "2017_844_1", "2017_844_1", "2017_844_1", "2017_844_2",
        "2017_844_2", "2017_844_2", "2017_844_2", "2017_844_3", "2017_844_3",
        "2017_844_3", "2017_844_3", "2017_845_1", "2017_845_1", "2017_845_1", 
        "2017_845_1", "2017_845_2","2017_845_2", "2017_845_2", "2017_845_2", 
        "2017_845_3","2017_845_3", "2017_845_3", "2017_845_3")
lat <- c(-30.6456, -29.5648, -27.6667, -31.5587, -30.6934, -29.3147, -23.0538, 
         -26.5877, -26.6923, -23.40865, -23.1143, -23.28331, -31.6456, -24.5648, 
         -27.6867, -31.4587, -30.6784, -28.3447, -23.0466, -27.5877, -26.8524, 
         -23.8855, -24.1143, -23.5874)
long <- c(-50.4879, -49.8715, -51.8716, -50.4456, -50.9842, -51.9787, -41.2343, 
          -40.2859, -40.19599, -41.64302, -41.58042, -41.55057, -50.4576, -48.8715, 
          -51.4566, -51.4456, -50.4477, -50.9937, -41.4789, -41.3859, -40.2536, 
          -41.6502, -40.5442, -41.4057)

df <- tibble(id = as.factor(id), sub_id  = as.factor(sub_id), lat, long)

#converting ​to sf
df.sf <- df %>% 
 ​sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)


#creating grid
xy <- sf::st_coordinates(df.sf)

grid = sf::st_make_grid(sf::st_bbox(df.sf),
                       ​cellsize = .1, square = FALSE) %>%
 ​sf::st_as_sf() 

#creating raster
r <- raster::raster(grid, res=0.1) 

#return grid because raster function changes number of cells 
grid2 <- rasterToPolygons(r, na.rm=F) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% mutate(cell=1:ncell(r))

#creating linestring to each sub_id
df.line <- df.sf %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(sub_id, id) %>%
  dplyr::summarize() %>%
  sf::st_cast("LINESTRING") 

#creating ID list
mylist<- split(df.line, df.line$id)

#separating one dataframe of list to test function
one_df <- df.line[df.line$id=="844",]
one_df$id <- droplevels(one_df$id)
one_df$sub_id <- droplevels(one_df$sub_id)
```

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here and it seems very complex. However, the specific error is caused because `intersect_list` has empty entries in the list, which cannot be joined because they are empty. If you modified the map function to only use non-empty items of `intersect_list` you would not get that error.

Comment: I think I get it, when I use one subset dataframe to run the function in steps, I do this ```one_df$id <- droplevels(one_df$id);
one_df$sub_id <- droplevels(one_df$sub_id) ``` then the problem does not occur. When I put the list inside the map, this is not done automatically then create the empty lists, right?

Comment: You were very accurate in your comment, I added ```%>% keep( ~ !is.null(.)``` below the ```intersect_list``` creation code inside function, and perfectly run in ```map()```. If you want to add an answer, make yourself comfortable.I think will edit the question for better understanding of the readers.

Comment: Nice, good to see you got it working. I'll add an answer when I get some time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, "it saved me". Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error is caused because `intersect_list` has empty items in the list, which cannot be joined because they are empty, and hence have no columns to join by. If you modified the map function to only use non-empty items of `intersect_list` you would not get that error.

As you noted in the comments, removing the empty list entries with `keep(intersect_list, ~ !is.null(.))` before mapping `left_join` onto the list items will fix the error.

However, I don't think this is the most elegant way to solve this problem. I might misunderstand what the goal is, but if it's to produce a raster from the total length of lines within each grid cell, I think a simpler approach without using `purrr` might work.

This is not the exact same as your product, but I'm keeping it simpler rn to illustrate an alternate approach. Here is a sum of the lengths in each cell as a `stars` object (similar to `raster` but plays better with the tidyverse and `sf`).

I'm starting off from your objects `one_df` and `grid`:

```
# Turn multiple lines into single MULTILINESTRING:
one_df %>% 
  st_union() -> 
  union_df

# Intersection of each grid cell with the MULTILINESTRING geometry:
grid %>% 
  st_intersection(union_df) -> 
  grid_lines 

# Get lengths:
grid_lines %>% 
  mutate(length = st_length(x)) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() ->
  grid_lengths

# Join the calculated lengths back with the spatial grid, 
# most of which will have NA for length
grid %>%
  left_join(grid_lengths, by = "cell") ->
  grid_with_lengths

# Rasterize the length field of the grid
grid_with_lengths %>% 
  dplyr::select(length) %>% 
  stars::st_rasterize() ->
  length_stars
  
  length_stars %>% mapview::mapview()
```

[image: stars object viewed with mapview]

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, I appreciate all the help I get here. I did it this complex way because I need that inside "ID" the length per cel for each sub-id is measured separately, and then calculate the average. But I'll try to adapt with your suggestion, I didn't know about the 'stars' package.

Comment: Cool. This some sort of animal movement data?

Comment: These data I posted here are random to example, so it has points at sea and on land. But the real ones are movements of humpback whales in Brazil. There are 30 animals but the data is modeled, so for each whale I have 50 trackings, thus requiring several loops.